# Animation in Angular 4 not working

Tags: angular, typescript

I am new to Angular 4 animations. After searching on the net for various tutorial I came up to one simple tutorial that animate the `ngIf` by using `translateY` transition. It was although working in his video tutorial but when I created demo on plunker it does not work as expected. Here is my  [plunker link](https://plnkr.co/edit/bAxkxbo3QEo7R5GZpKdW?p=preview) . Any idea whats wrong with it?

Answer (score 2):

Gotcha! I have to include `web-animations.min.js` polyfill to support my Safari browser on Mac and it works like a charm.